# How can I make sprites transition ever 10 seconds to a new sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am making a credits scene for my Unity3D game and am having trouble with the background images. I have 5 sprites that I want to use for background images. I am fairly new to C# so can someone help me make a script to swap sprites every 10-15 seconds?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're going to have better luck getting answers to questions like this after you've shown some attempts at figuring it out yourself. Once you can show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem try asking again.

Comment: I have been trying for over a week. No luck. And I really don't see how I can show progress that I have not made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [an animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html).

Unity's animation editor will let you create an animation for *any* property of *any* component attached to a GameObject. This includes changing its sprite.

Add a property, point it at the sprite component, and create keyframes every 10 seconds on the timeline. At those keyframes, change the sprite's image.

Save. That's it!

Comment: @EthanK-B I'm not either. :B

Comment: It can even be done easier. Open the animation window while having your animator controller selected, create a new animation, drag your 5 sprites into the animation window time-line, adjust the speed of the animation, done.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an ideal use for Coroutines: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Here's a rough example of how it can be done.

```
public List<Sprite> spritesToSwap; // contains all the sprites to loop through

IEnumerator SwapSprites() {
    int spriteIndex = 0;
    while (true) {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spritesToSwap[spriteIndex];
            // ^ replace the sprite
        spriteIndex++;
        if (spriteIndex == spritesToSwap.Count) spriteIndex = 0;
            // ^ loop back to first sprite
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f); // adjust this time as desired
    }
}
```

Call `StartCoroutine(SwapSprites())` when you want to [start it](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html), and `StopCoroutine(SwapSprites())` when/if you want to end it.

Comment: Can you explain this to me more? I am not sure I am doing something right?

Comment: Sure... but keep in mind this approach (coroutines) is completely different from using Animations, which were suggested earlier; you'll have to choose one or the other :) Animations are probably easier than my suggestion, actually. Anyways, the idea is that a Coroutine gets Started, runs like a regular function, swaps the sprite, then "yields" control for 10 seconds (where it says `yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f)`). Once the ten seconds are up, it loops, and the sprite is swapped again. The Coroutines link in my answer should explain more... does that make sense?

Comment: Mostly. Can you tell me exactly how I get the sprite rend part of the script to work? I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: I edited the code and swapped out the SpriteRenderer variable for a GetComponent() call, it should be easier to get it working now, no need to initialize the variable

Comment: What do you mean by export? Like, when you build the game as an executable? That's strange, there's nothing in here that's specific to the Editor, I think. Did you fill in the `spritesToSwap` list using the Inspector?